# Evaluating a SymPy expression that refers to variables having "nan" values

Tags: python, sympy

I've been using `parse_expr()` function of [`SymPy`](https://www.sympy.org) to evaluate string expressions that refer to variables. Now I'm faced with a problem parsing an expression that contains a variable which has a `"nan"` value. I've tried to replace the `"nan"` value with `0` by passing something like `{"nan": 0}` as the `local_dict` or `global_dict` parameter, but couldn't find a way to make it work.

How can I parse and evaluate an expression that refers to variables having `"nan"` values? Can I map `"nan"` to specific value by passing parameters to `parse_expr()`?

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
>>> data = {'result': {'a': 'nan', 'b': 123}}
>>> expr = "result['b'] + 123"    # <-- This works well.
>>> parse_expr(expr, data)
>>> 246
>>> expr = "result['a'] + 123"    # <-- This doesn't work.
>>> parse_expr(expr, data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../sympy-1.2rc1-py3.6.egg/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 950, in parse_expr
    return eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
  File ".../sympy-1.2rc1-py3.6.egg/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 863, in eval_expr
code, global_dict, local_dict)  # take local objects in preference
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be str, not Integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual `nan` values are understood by SymPy, and are treated appropriately:

```
from math import nan
data = {'result': {'a': nan, 'b': 123}}
expr = "result['a'] + 123"
parse_expr(expr, local_dict=data)   # returns nan
```

The result is correct: nan plus any number is nan.

But your dictionary contains a string `'nan'` which has no special meaning: it could be `'foo'` just as well. This is just bad data, so you should fix the data before passing it to SymPy:

```
data = {'result': {'a': 'nan', 'b': 123}}
for key in data['result']:
    if data['result'][key] == 'nan':
        data['result'][key] = 0
```

Now `parse_expr(expr, local_dict=data)` returns 123.

Answer (score -1):

Sympy should be built to handle `nan`s. The problem is that it does not automatically convert `'nan'` to a floating-point `nan`. For example, the following also fails:

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
>>> data = {'result': {'a': '321', 'b': 123}}
>>> expr = "result['b'] + 123"    # <-- This works well.
>>> parse_expr(expr, data)
246
>>> expr = "result['a'] + 123"    # <-- This doesn't work.
>>> parse_expr(expr, data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jonathan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 950, in parse_expr
    return eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
  File "/home/jonathan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 863, in eval_expr
    code, global_dict, local_dict)  # take local objects in preference
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Integer") to str
```

Using a floating-point `nan` rather than a string works:

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
>>> from math import nan
>>> data = {'result': {'a': nan, 'b': 123}}
>>> expr = "result['b'] + 123"    # <-- This works well.
>>> parse_expr(expr, data)
246
>>> expr = "result['a'] + 123"    # <-- This also works.
>>> parse_expr(expr, data)
nan
```